# Shopware 6 Store Activation causes generic Error Message in Admin UI

Tags: php, out-of-memory, shopware, shopware6

How to make sure that activating the Shopware store is either working properly *or* throwing a proper error message, either in the UI or in a server log?

Trying to activate the Shopware store in the `/admin` UI of a working Shopware 6.4.17.2 instance causes different error messages that have no corresponding entry in the server side log files. Clicking "retry" after getting a generic error message causes an "memory exhausted" error although the numbers don't add up (allocating 6M seems to exhaust a 134M limit).

Error details:
The error message simply says "Error during activation. Please try again. If that does not work, ask your administrator for help." and a blue "Retry" button below.

There is nothing relevant in the error log (only frontend 404 errors), although the admin UI's browser console shows that there has been a 500 Internal Server error, causing follow-up client side errors:

```
/api/_action/extension/activate/plugin/SwagExtensionStore
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

/api/notification/message?limit=5:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

/api/_info/queue.json
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

/bundles/administration/static/js/commons.js?1668607807231938
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at commons.js?1668607807231938:1:203362
```

After retrying, at least I get a real error message, this time about a seemingly exhausted memory limit, claiming that trying to allocate 6M (6242480 bytes) has exhausted the current limit of 143M (134217728 bytes).

```
Internal Server Error
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6242480 bytes)
I had a similar misleading memory limit message recently.
```

Possible solutions?

Should I raise the memory limit in `php.ini` even further?

Should I prefer to use the CLI rather than the admin UI for tasks like this (specifying custom memory limits if needed)?

How can I make sure to get proper error messages? The 500 Internal Server Error from the API call should have been logged somewhere, but it wasn't, at least not in the latest  `htdocs/shopware/var/log/production*.log`

Do we have to explicitly configure logging of these kind of errors, or is there another log file where this should have been logged?

Comment: In general you should prefer installing plugins over the CLI, as you have way more control over memory limits or timeouts and the error messages are probably also easier to understand.

Did you tried to install via CLI already? Did you get an error there as well?

Comment: @j_elfering how to activate the store via CLI? There is `bin/console store:download` to download specific plugins, and `bin/console store:login`, not sure if the latter is the same as "activating the store" in the admin UI, and which password is expected when no username is mentioned. The usage information is only printed after the login failed, so we can specify a username and/or shopwareId: `store:login [-i|--shopwareId SHOPWAREID] [-p|--password PASSWORD] [-u|--user USER] [-g|--host [HOST]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]]`

Comment: @j_elfering trying `bin/console store:login` with shopwareId and password, I get a "User not found" exception. I used my "Customer id" (335xxx) as shown after logging in on the website account.shopware.com.

Comment: ... and everything is silent. If I ever find out, I will self-answer my own question. What happened to the Shopware forums anyway?